# Maven with Url Argument Not Allowed in build.gradle repositories

Tags: maven, gradle, jitpack

I'm trying to include a jitpack [library](https://github.com/Dwolla/dwolla-v2-kotlin) in my kotlin project via Maven, but the syntax i'm told to follow in the docs to include it in my project doesn't work. Specifically, when I try to add maven() in my project-level gradle file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven(url = "https://jitpack.io") {
        name = "jitpack"
    }
}
```

I get this error in my intelliJ IDE: `maven' in 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure<java.lang.String>)`. Something seems to be wrong with the inclusion of a url as a parameter in the `maven()` call.

I've tried to change up the syntax to the match the example shown in the [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        name = "jitpack"
    }
}
```

But I still can't access the lib in my code after implementing the dependency in my module-level gradle file.

Is there a conflict with using mavenCentral() and maven() together? It seems like the issue is solely about the syntax of using a url as a param to maven(). What can I do to fix this and gain access to the jitpack lib I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the maven call to my project-level build.gradle file instead of at the app level.

Like this:

Module level **build.gradle**

```
repositories{
    //added maven repo here instead of the app-level build.gradle file
    maven { url = "https://jitpack.io"}
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.github.Dwolla:dwolla-v2-kotlin:0.2.0"
}
```